# For Riemannian submersion, Horizontal lift of $pp_1$, then $p_1p_2$ equals $pp_2$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f:M\to N$ be a Riemannian submersion and a fiber bundle. Then for every $p\in N$, there is a nbh $B(p,r)\subset N$, s.t. $f^{-1}(B(p,r))$ is homeo to $B(p,r) \times f^{-1}(p)$. Suppose that for any $p_1, p_2\in B(p,r)$, the geodesic connecting $p_1,p_2$ is unique.

Starting from a point $x\in f^{-1}(p)$, suppose that the Horizontal lift of geodesic $pq_i$ ends at $x_i\in f^{-1}(p_i)$. Do the Horizontal lifting of geodesic $p_1p_2$ starting at $x_1$ ends at $x_2$?

Comment: By the geodesic $pq_i$ you meant the geodesic $pp_i$ for some $p_i \in B(p,r)$, $i=1,2$?

Comment: No.  Just consider the example $M=\mathrm{SO}(3)$ with its standard biïnvariant metric and $N=S^2$ with $f(e_1\,e_2\,e_3) = e_1$ starting at $p=(e_1,e_2,e_3) = I_3$, and you'll see that this doesn't hold.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Can you explain this example in detail?  It seems to me that there is no problem in the following answer.

Comment: @mathmetricgeometry: Have you tried the calculation? The example I gave is very explicit and can easily be done by hand by elementary ODE. As for what is wrong with Lezkus' answer: It's obvious that  $f_{|U}:U\to B(p,r)$ is *not* an isometry, so something else must be meant. Presumably, the section $s$ is to be constructed using lifting of geodesics starting at $p$ to horizontal curves starting at $x$. Then we have a surface $\Sigma = s(B(p,r))\subset U$. Perhaps, Lezkus meant to claim that $s:B(p,r)\to \Sigma$ is a isometry, but there is no reason for this, and it's not true in my example.

Comment: @RobertBryant: What if we assume in addition that $N$ is flat?  Is there a counter example?

Comment: @mathmetricgeometry:  Yes, here is a counterexample:  Let $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ with metric $g = \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 + (\mathrm{d}z + x\,\mathrm{d}y)^2$ and let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be $f(x,y,z) = (x,y)$.  Then $M$ is a fiber bundle over $N = \mathbb{R}^2$ and, letting $h =  \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 $ on $N$ (which is flat), we have that $f$ is a Riemannian submersion.  You can now easily check that starting at $p=(0,0)$ and lifting to $x=(0,0,0)$, you don't get the desired result with $p_1 = (1,1)$ and $p_2=(1,0)$.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I realised, by Robert Bryant's kind comments, that this just happens whenever the metric is flat so that $\mathcal{H}$ is integrable.